# How can I make threading more flexible?

Tags: list-manipulation, function-construction

Threading automatically with `Listable` functions requires the argument expressions to have the same length (or for one of them to be atomic). For nested lists the threading will continue down through the levels, provided the lengths are the same at each level. So, for example, these all work because the `Dimensions` of the two lists are the same at the first $n$ levels:

```
Array[#&, {10, 5, 3}] + Array[#&, {10}];
Array[#&, {10, 5, 3}] + Array[#&, {10, 5}];
Array[#&, {10, 5, 3}] + Array[#&, {10, 5, 3}];
```

whereas this doesn't work because the outer `Dimensions` don't match ($10\neq 5$):

```
Array[#&, {10, 5, 3}] + Array[#&, {5, 3}];
(*  Thread::tdlen: Objects of unequal length ... cannot be combined. *)
```

But there *is* an obvious interpretation of the above code, which is to map the addition over the outer level of the first argument, i.e. to add the second 5x3 array to each of the ten 5x3 arrays in the first argument.

A more easily visualised example is adding an offset to a list of coordinates:

```
coords = {{1, 2}, {3, 4}, {5, 6}, {7, 8}};
offset = {0, 10};
```

One way is to explicity `Map` the addition over the coordinate list:

```
result = # + offset & /@ coords
(* {{1, 12}, {3, 14}, {5, 16}, {7, 18}} *)
```

If the coordinate list was very long, a more efficient approach using `Transpose` might be preferred:

```
result = Transpose[Transpose[coords] + offset]
(* {{1, 12}, {3, 14}, {5, 16}, {7, 18}} *)
```

Neither of these is particularly readable though. It would be nice to have a "smart" threading function that would identify that the second dimension of `coords` (length 2) matches the first dimensions of `offset` (also length 2), allowing the code to be written very readably:

```
result = smartThread[ coords + offset ]
(* {{1, 12}, {3, 14}, {5, 16}, {7, 18}} *)
```

How can I write such a `smartThread` function, which will take an expression of the form `func_[a_, b_]` and match up the various dimensions in `a` and `b` to do this kind of flexible threading?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

My own solution looks like this:

```
SetAttributes[smartThread, HoldAll];

smartThread[f_[a_?ArrayQ, b_?ArrayQ], dir : -1 | 1 : -1] := Module[{da, db, or, o, g, t},
  or = Function[{x, y, d}, Select[Permutations @ Range @ Length[x], 
   x[[#[[;; Length[y]]]]] == y &][[d]] ~Check~ Return[$Failed, Module]];
  t = #1 ~Transpose~ Ordering[#2] &;
  g = If[MemberQ[Attributes[f], Listable], f, Function[Null, f[##], Listable]];
  {da, db} = Dimensions /@ {a, b};
  If[Length[da] >= Length[db],
    t[a, o = or[da, db, dir]] ~g~ b, 
    a ~g~ t[b, o = or[db, da, dir]]]
   ~Transpose~ o]
```

The function works by examining the dimensions of both input lists to determine which dimensions are "shared" (ie. have the same length) by both inputs. One of the input lists (the one with the greater `ArrayDepth`) is transposed such that the shared dimensions are outermost. This allows the function to thread over those dimensions, after which the `Transpose` is reversed.

### Straightforward examples

By "straightforward", I mean cases where there is no ambiguity about how to match up the dimensions of the two input lists. For `Listable` functions like `Plus` and `Times` the `smartThread` function works as you would expect:

```
smartThread[{{1, 2}, {3, 4}, {5, 6}} + {10, 0}]
(* {{11, 2}, {13, 4}, {15, 6}} *)

smartThread[{{1, 2}, {3, 4}, {5, 6}} * {10, 0}]
(* {{10, 0}, {30, 0}, {50, 0}} *)
```

Functions which are not normally `Listable` are replaced internally by versions which are, so you get `Thread`-like behaviour:

```
smartThread[{{1, 2}, {3, 4}, {5, 6}} ~ Max ~ {10, 0}]
(* {{10, 2}, {10, 4}, {10, 6}} *)

smartThread[{{1, 2}, {3, 4}, {5, 6}} ~ f ~ {10, 0}]
(* {{f[1, 10], f[2, 0]}, {f[3, 10], f[4, 0]}, {f[5, 10], f[6, 0]}} *)
```

It should work with nested lists of any depth, provided the dimensions can be matched up. Note that the output has the same shape as whichever input has the greater `ArrayDepth`:

```
smartThread[Array[#&, {5, 7, 2, 10, 3, 4}] + Array[#&, {10, 7, 3}]] // Dimensions
(* {5, 7, 2, 10, 3, 4} *)

smartThread[Array[#&, {10, 7, 3}] + Array[#&, {5, 7, 2, 10, 3, 4}]] // Dimensions
(* {5, 7, 2, 10, 3, 4} *)
```

### Equal `ArrayDepth` case

If both input lists have the **same** `ArrayDepth`, the output will be the same shape as the first one:

```
smartThread[Array[# &, {10, 2}] + Array[# &, {2, 10}]] // Dimensions
(* {10, 2} *)

smartThread[Array[# &, {2, 10}] + Array[# &, {10, 2}]] // Dimensions
(* {2, 10} *)
```

### Dimension matching ambiguites

There is not always a single unique way to match up the dimensions of the input lists. Consider for example `smartThread[a + b]` where `Dimensions[a] = {2, 3, 2}` and `Dimensions[b] = {3, 2}`. The default behaviour of `smartThread` is to match the dimensions *innermost first*, so the result would be equivalent to `{a[[1]] + b, a[[2]] + b}`:

```
smartThread[Array[0 &, {2, 3, 2}] + {{1, 2}, {3, 4}, {5, 6}}]
(* {{{1, 2}, {3, 4}, {5, 6}}, {{1, 2}, {3, 4}, {5, 6}}} *)
```

If it is required to match the dimensions outermost first, you can supply +1 as a second argument to `smartThread`:

```
smartThread[Array[0 &, {2, 3, 2}] + {{1, 2}, {3, 4}, {5, 6}}, 1]
(* {{{1, 1}, {3, 3}, {5, 5}}, {{2, 2}, {4, 4}, {6, 6}}} *)
```

More generally, setting the second argument to *n* causes the code to select the *n*'th valid permutation of the dimensions.

**Note:**
I would personally recommend thinking twice before using `smartThread` in cases where there is ambiguity over how to match dimensions in the input lists. The motivation for writing it was to allow simple constructs like `smartThread[coordinateList + offset]`, increasing readability for code where the intention is intuitively obvious. In situations where that isn't the case, it potentially makes the code less clear than using something like `Map` or `Transpose` explicitly.

Comment: By the way, `smartThread[f[{a}, {{b}, {c}}]]` swaps the order and returns `{{f[b, a]}, {f[c, a]}}`

Comment: Thanks, @Rojo, good catch. I must have only tested it on `Orderless` functions...

Comment: I've patched it up using a third argument to indicate if `a` and `b` have been swapped, but I'm trying to think of a neater way to handle it.

Comment: I'm still trying to get a clear idea of the general behaviour expected. For example, is the output of `smartThread@f[{{x[1], x[2]}}, {{y[1]}, {y[2]}}]` and `smartThread@f[{{x[1]}, {x[2]}}, {{y[1], y[2]}}]` what you expect? I mean, the dimensions of the output can depend on the order of the lists? Or is that a bonus case that doesn't need to be handled?

Comment: Also, check the output of `smartThread@f[h@1, {2}]`

Comment: @Rojo, your first two examples are as expected. The output has to be the same shape as one of the inputs, normally  whichever one has the greater `ArrayDepth`, but if they both have the same depth the output takes the shape of the first input.

Comment: It won't work with heads other than `List` - I should put an `?ArrayQ` check in the pattern.

Answer (score 1):

In *v13.1* (now available on Wolfram Cloud) [`Threaded`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Threaded.html) is introduced:

```
coords = {{1, 2}, {3, 4}, {5, 6}, {7, 8}};
offset = {0, 10};
coords+Threaded@offset
```

[image]