# Multiplying two dimensional data by a constant

Tags: list-manipulation

I have a list of lists of the form:

```
{{1, 2}, {2, 4}, {2, 8}}
```

But I want to multiply only the second dimension of that data by a constant.  I know I could do this with a loop but that is "dirty".  There has to be a better way.  For example if I multiply the second dimension by 2 I would get:

```
{{1, 4}, {2, 8}, {2, 16}}
```

Comment: [`smartThread[{{1, 2}, {2, 4}, {2, 8}}*{1, 2}]`](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/23395/how-can-i-make-threading-more-flexible)

Comment: `Transpose[{1, 2} Transpose[lst]]` and  `ScalingTransform[{1, 2}][lst]` are other possibilities.  Both from an old MathGroup post by [Carl Woll](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/45431/carl-woll), according to my notes.  The first one seems to be very fast.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You can also do it this way:

```
{{1, 2}, {2, 4}, {2, 8}} /. {x_, y_} -> {x, 2 y}
```

Which gives:

```
{{1, 4}, {2, 8}, {2, 16}}
```

You can change `2` in `2 y` to whatever constant you want. This method is flexible because, say you want to multiply the first dimension by a different constant you just put that number in front of `x`. E.g. Suppose you want to multiply the first dimension by `3` and the second by `2`, you simply write:

```
 {{1, 2}, {2, 4}, {2, 8}} /. {x_, y_} -> {3 x, 2 y}
```

And this accomplishes the desired task.

EDIT: Using Pure Functions.

```
{#[[1]], 2 #[[2]]} & /@ {{1, 2}, {2, 4}, {2, 8}}

{First[#], 2 Last[#]} & /@ {{1, 2}, {2, 4}, {2, 8}}
```

Answer (score 18):

```
arr = {{1, 2}, {2, 4}, {2, 8}};
arr[[All,2]] *= 2;
```

Comment: Based on [this principle](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/3077/121) I favor this answer.  However, it should be noted that this modifies `arr`, so a copy should be modified if the original should be unchanged.

Answer (score 12):

Works nicely:

```
{{1, 2}, {2, 4}, {2, 8}}.DiagonalMatrix[{1, 2}]
```

`DiagonalMatrix[]` is particularly convenient for scaling rows or columns.

---

From [whuber](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/91):

> Multiplying by a diagonal matrix is fast for up to somewhere between 100 and 1000 columns; beyond that, a solution modeled after `Transpose[{1, 2} * Transpose[a]]` becomes superior. Even better for such large matrices is `a . SparseArray[Band[{1, 1}] -> {1, 2}]`; this is superior to both once there are 20 columns or so.

Comment: +1. Multiplying by a diagonal matrix is fast for up to somewhere between $100$ and $1000$ columns; beyond that, a solution modeled after `Transpose[{1, 2} * Transpose[a]]` becomes superior. Even better for such large matrices is `a . SparseArray[Band[{1, 1}] -> {1,2}]`; this is superior to both once there are $20$ columns or so.

Comment: @whuber as J. M. made this post wiki please include that comment in the answer.

Answer (score 12):

I like to use `Apply` for this kind of task.

```
{#1, 2 #2} & @@@ {{1, 2}, {2, 4}, {2, 8}}
```

Answer (score 8):

```
Cases[{{1, 2}, {2, 4}, {2, 8}}, {x_, y_} -> {x, 2 y}]

Table[{First@i, Last@i*2}, {i, {{1, 2}, {2, 4}, {2, 8}}}]

{#1, 2 #2} & @@ Transpose@{{1, 2}, {2, 4}, {2, 8}} // Transpose


data = RandomReal[10, {10^6, 2}];
r1 = {#1, 2 #2} & @@ Transpose@data // Transpose; // Timing
r2 = {#1, 2 #2} & @@@ data; // Timing
r1 == r2
(*
{0.109201, Null}
{3.229221, Null}
True
*)
```

Answer (score 4):

Here's another -general- approach, using `MapAt`. Maybe not the fastest, but I think it is pretty transparent and configurable:

```
MapAt[2 # &, list, {1 ;;, 2}]
```

or (thanks to @RunnyKine)

```
MapAt[2 # &, list, {All, 2}]
```

or interestingly, faster:

```
MapAt[(2 #) &, #, 2] & /@ list
```

**Timings**

Using `data` as in @chyanog's post, I get:

```
MapAt[2 # &, data, {1 ;;, 2}]; // Timing
```

> {1.078534, Null}

```
MapAt[(2 #) &, #, 2] & /@ data; // Timing
```

> {0.111480, Null}

(where my machine is about 2x faster than chyanog's, so his solution definitely is faster, by about factor 3) (and it doesn't make sense to compare to all the others, as e.g. `DiagonalMatrix` is suited for this task very well, but not as configurable)

Comment: +1. You can also use `{All, 2}` in place of `{1;;, 2}` with `MapAt`

Answer (score 3):

As of *v13.1*, we can also use `Threaded`:

```
{{1, 2}, {2, 4}, {2, 8}} Threaded[{1, 2}]
(* {{1, 4}, {2, 8}, {2, 16}} *)
```

Answer (score 3):

Using `ReplaceAt` (new in 13.1)

```
list = {{1, 2}, {2, 4}, {2, 8}};

ReplaceAt[list, x_ :> 2 x, {All, 2}]
```

{{1, 4}, {2, 8}, {2, 16}}

`ReplaceAt` has the advantage that we can easily impose additional conditions:

```
ReplaceAt[list, x_ /; x > 2 :> 2 x, {All, 2}]
```

{{1, 2}, {2, 8}, {2, 16}}

Answer (score 3):

**Using `SubsetMap`:**

```
list = {{1, 2}, {2, 4}, {2, 8}};
SubsetMap[Times[#, 2] &, list, {All, 2}]
```

---

> {{1, 4}, {2, 8}, {2, 16}}

---

To impose more conditions:

```
SubsetMap[Map[If[# > 2, 2 #, #] &], list, {All, 2}]
```

> {{1, 2}, {2, 8}, {2, 16}}