# Manipulating Elements in a Triple-Nested List

Tags: list-manipulation, partitions

I have been working on a triple-nested list, called ***datasections***, of the given form:

```
{{{44.5, 0.00185}, {45.2, 0.00186}, {45.5, 0.00186},...},
 {{48.6, 0.00186}, {49.2, 0.00209}, {49.9, 0.00109},...},
 ...
}
```

I want to multiply all the secondary values within the lowest level of the list by a constant value, while retaining the primary values.

For example, if the constant value was *2*, then the outcome would be:

```
{{{44.5, 0.0037}, {45.2, 0.00372}, {45.5, 0.00372},...},
 {{48.6, 0.00372}, {49.2, 0.00418}, {49.9, 0.00218},...},
 ...
}
```

Currently, I have written a code which accomplishes the wanted task, but this code loses the triple nested list structure, which I need to retain.

```
{Join[
 Partition[
  Flatten[datasections[[]], 1][[All, 1]], 1],
 Partition[
  Flatten[datasections[[]], 1][[All, 2]]*2, 1], 2 
]}
```

Is there a simple way to accomplish the task at hand?

Comment: Possible duplicates: [(3069)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/3069/121), [(24817)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/24817/121)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to "safe" your original data make a copy.

```
data = {{{44.5, 0.00185}, {45.2, 0.00186}, {45.5, 0.00186}}, {{48.6, 0.00186}, {49.2, 0.00209}, {49.9, 0.00109}}};

copy = data;

copy[[All, All, 2]] *= 2

copy // MatrixForm
```

[image]

If you want to change `data` permanently it's just

```
 data[[All, All, 2]] *= 2
```

You obtain the same result with `ReplaceAll`

```
data /. {a_, b_?NumericQ} :> {a, 2 b}
```

(`ReplaceAll` can become slow on large lists)

Comment: Just to be clear, each comma within [[...]] goes one layer deeper into the list?

If so, that make all my operations significantly easier.

Comment: Exactly, you might read the documentation about `Part`.

Comment: Thanks for the help!  That documentation really cleared up my confusion about the list structure.

Answer (score 7):

This command may be helpful to you:

```
MapAt[2 # &,
 {{{44.5, 0.00185}, {45.2, 0.00186}, {45.5, 0.00186}},
  {{48.6, 0.00186}, {49.2, 0.00209}, {49.9, 0.00109}}}, {All, All, 2}]
```

It produces this output

```
{{{44.5, 0.0037}, {45.2, 0.00372}, {45.5, 0.00372}}, 
 {{48.6, 0.00372}, {49.2, 0.00418}, {49.9, 0.00218}}}
```