# Extending listability to coordinates

Tags: list-manipulation

I noticed that one can subtract a since real number value from all elements in an array by writing something like

```
{5, 4, 3, 2, 1} - 5
```

which outputs `{0, -1, -2, -3, -4}`.  However, this doesn't seem to extend to coordinates, where we get an "objects of unequal length" error for a command like

```
{{5, 4}, {5, 2}, {5, 1}, {5, -5}} - {2, 2}
```

Is there a way to easily do make something like above work so that `{2,2}` is subtracted from each list item automatically?

Comment: Hmm, I would `Map` it: `# - {2, 2} & /@ {{5, 4}, {5, 2}, {5, 1}, {5, -5}}` (*I'm not posting it as an answer because I'm looking for duplicate ;)*)

Comment: Possible duplicate: [(23395)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/23395/121)