# Simple subtraction question

Tags: list-manipulation

I have two lists.

```
a = {{2, 2}, {3, 3}, {4, 4}, {5, 5}};
b = {1, 1};
```

I want to subtract `a` from `b` and want to get

```
{{1, 1}, {2, 2}, {3, 3}, {4, 4}}`
```

When I tried `Subtract[a, b]`, I got an error. How do I fix this?

Comment: If you don't know start with `Map`, i.e. `# - b & /@ a`.

Comment: Basic issue as Artes has shown or duplicate of [flexible threading](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/23395/5478)

Comment: Even better canditate for duplicate [Extending listability to coordinates](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/31894/5478)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Artes comment as an answer.

```
a = {{2, 2}, {3, 3}, {4, 4}, {5, 5}};
b = {1, 1};
(# - b)& /@ a
```

> ```
> {{1, 1}, {2, 2}, {3, 3}, {4, 4}}
> ```

In the special case of your example, because of the way *Mathematica* defines addition of a scalar to a list, you can do

```
a - 1
```

> ```
> {{1, 1}, {2, 2}, {3, 3}, {4, 4}}
> ```

`a - x` will work for any pair of the form `b = {x, x}`.

Comment: Maybe you could add: in this special case the same result can be achieved simply with `a - 1`.

Comment: @Jens. Good idea. Done.