# How to extend "List-of-numbers-with-number" arithmetic to "List-of-X-with-X" arithmetic?

Tags: list-manipulation, linear-algebra

I'll start with a couple of examples (since this is all one can get from the documentation anyway).

First, adding lists of numbers equal length is done term-by-term.  E.g. `{8, 2, 5} + {3, 0, 3}` evaluates to `{11, 2, 8}`.

Second, adding a list of numbers to a single number is done by, effectively, "broadcasting" the single number into a list of the same size as that of the other addend, and then the same term-by-term addition as before is applied.  For example `{1, 2, 3} + 5` evaluates to `{6, 7, 8}`.

Conceptually, one could imagine extending this scheme to the case of adding a list `L` to a list-of-lists `L^2`.  First "broadcast" `L` into a list of the appropriate number of copies of `L`, and then add the two lists-of-lists "term-by-term".  For example, following this scheme, `{1, 2} + {{5, 9}, {9, 7}, {1, 7}}` would evaluate to `{{6, 11}, {10, 9}, {2, 9}}`.

To my surprise, however, *Mathematica* won't play along: The last sum would fail with an error beginning with `Thread::tdlen: Objects of unequal length ...`  (The same goes for the remaining "basic operations", `-`, `*`, and `/`.)

What's the simplest way to carry out this proposed extension of arithmetic between a single object of type *X* and a `List` of objects of type *X* (assuming that arithmetic between single objects of type *X* is defined)?

Comment: `Map` is the simplest approach. This question seems to be a duplicate of [How to make threading more flexible](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/23395/5478). Also, notice that you have said: "add the two lists-of-lists "term-by-term"" ant then you are doing something different.

Comment: @Kuba: thanks for your comments.  I can't follow your last point.  Just to be clear, if `A, B, C, D` are all of some type *X* for which addition is defined, I'm saying that `A + {B, C, D}` should evaluate to `{A + B, A + C, A + D}`.  If *X* happens to be "`List` of 2 integers", then the foregoing implies that `{1, 2} + {{5, 9}, {9, 7}, {1, 7}}` would evaluate to `{{1, 2} + {5, 9}, {1, 2} + {9, 7}, {1, 2} + {1, 7}} = {{6, 11}, {10, 9}, {2, 9}}`.

Comment: but why do you think `{1,2}+{{5,9},..` should evaluate to `{{1,2}+{5,9}, ...`. This would be inconsistent with your next wish that `{a,b} + {c,d}`->`{a+c,b+d}`. Those are different ways to proceed even though they look similar. Mathematica does automatically as much as it can (*here*), then you have to specify what do you want to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an alternative to `Map`:

```
{1, 2} + Transpose@{{5, 9}, {9, 7}, {1, 7}} // Transpose
(* {{6, 11}, {10, 9}, {2, 9}} *)
```

It can be faster than `Map`, too:

```
m = RandomInteger[{1, 9}, {10^6, 2}];

{1, 2} + Transpose@m // Transpose // AbsoluteTiming // First
(* 0.025621 *)

{1, 2} + # & /@ m // AbsoluteTiming // First
(* 0.148701 *)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 i@l_ := l + {1, 2}
 i /@ {{5, 9}, {9, 7}, {1, 7}}
```

Comment: This is really what Kuba said.