# MapThread Alternatives

Tags: list-manipulation, performance-tuning, map

I want to add two matrices, the first one containing a 2D vector at each position the other one a list of 2D vectors. The 2D vector from the first matrix should be added to each of the 2D vectors at the same position in the other matrix. The way I know of is using MapThread, but is there a faster way?

So basically I have two matrices defined like this:

```
MA = Table[RandomReal[], {i, 10}, {j, 10}, {k, 2}];
MB = Table[RandomReal[], {i, 10}, {j, 10}, {k, 3}, {l, 2}];
```

The output of `MA+MB` should be `Mout[[i,j]] = {MA[[i,j]]+MB[[i,j,1]],MA[[i,j]]+MB[[i,j,1]],MA[[i,j]]+MB[[i,j,1]]}` for each pair of indices `i,j`.

The one method I am using right now is a combination of `MapThread` and `Map`:

```
Mout = MapThread[Function[{x,y},x+#&/@y],{MA,MB},2]
```

This works but is rather slow. Is there a faster and maybe more elegant way to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A fast way to do it is to transpose `MB` to swap levels 3 and 4. `Plus` will then automatically thread over the arrays, after which you transpose back again:

```
Mout = Transpose[MA + Transpose[MB, {1, 2, 4, 3}], {1, 2, 4, 3}];
```

In the [question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/23395/862) Kuba linked to, my `smartThread` function attempts to automate this method. You would use it like this:

```
Mout = smartThread[MA + MB, 1];
```

However, this is slower than the explicit `Transpose` code above.

Comment: As speed is important I will stick to the proposed Tranposition Method. Thank you.