# How to use Map inside MapThread?

Tags: list-manipulation, map

Given this input

```
lst1 = {{a, b, c}, {d, e, f}};
lst2 = {1, 2};
```

and the goal is to generate this output

```
{  {{1, a}, {1, b}, {1, c}}, 
   {{2, d}, {2, e}, {2, f}}
}
```

Perfect candidate for [MapThread](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/MapThread.html) So I made this diagram first to figure what the function I want to map should be

[image]

So the function to use inside `MapThread`, needs to also use `Map` itself (in order to map each item into the other list). So I came up with this:

```
lst1 = {{a, b, c}, {d, e, f}};
lst2 = {1, 2};
foo[i_, lst_List] := List[i, #] & /@ lst
MapThread[foo[#1, #2] &, {Range[Length@lst2], lst1}]
(*  {  {{1,a}, {1,b}, {1,c}},       {{2,d}, {2,e}, {2,f}}   }  *)
```

*Now here is the question*: Is there a way to do the above without having to define an explicit function but using pure function inside `MapThread`?

I was getting conflict with `#` mapping. This is sort of the thing I was trying to do, but can't get the syntax right

```
(*invalid, for illustration only *)
MapThread[ 
 Function[{idx, lst},List[idx, #] & /@ lst] &  ?? ??    ,{Range[Length@lst2],lst1}]
```

Or if you know of a better approach to do this, that will be fine as well.

Comment: Get rid of that last `&` in your illustration as you already have the long form of using `Function[   ]`. You can also use `Thread[{##}] &` as the function for `MapThread`

Comment: Thanks, I guess I was close :)  can you show how to use {##}? I am not good with ##, I know # only now.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
MapThread[Thread[{##}] &, {lst2, lst1}] 

Map[Thread, {lst2, lst1}\[Transpose]]
```

[`##`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/SlotSequence.html) is used so `Thread` gets called like `Thread[{1, {a, b, c}}]` As `MapThread` gives two arguments in this case it is equivalent to `Thread[{#1, #2}]&` and `Composition[Thread, List]`

Comment: `Thread[{##}]` is nice since it is shorter. I have to read about it, as never saw it before.

Comment: V10 style: `MapThread[Thread@*List, {lst2, lst1}]`

Answer (score 8):

Very similar to ssch's second answer, but sometimes `Thread` feels more natural than `Transpose`:

```
Thread /@ Thread @ {lst2, lst1}
```

Less clear, but more interesting, is to make a `Listable` version of `List`:

```
Function[, {##}, Listable][lst2, lst1]
```

You could also use my [smartThread](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/23396/862) function:

```
smartThread @ {lst2, lst1}
```

Comment: smartThread is so cool. I did not know about it, will start using it. I wish Mathematica had such functions build in. I am starting to think the we need a major overhaul of number of Mathematica core functions to add more options to them and make them more flexible. Sometimes I feel it takes too much work and skill to do some basic manipulation of lists.

Answer (score 6):

A `Map/MapThread`-less solution

```
Transpose@Inner[List, lst2, lst1, List]
```

Answer (score 4):

```
MapThread[Function[{u, b}, List[b, #] & /@ u], {lst1, lst2}];
```

and the reverse example with `Slots` on top:

```
MapThread[Map[Function[u, {#2, u}], #] &, {lst1, lst2}]
```

> ```
> {{{1, a}, {1, b}, {1, c}}, {{2, d}, {2, e}, {2, f}}}
> ```

---

Approach with `MapIndexed`:

```
MapIndexed[{lst2[[#2[[1]]]], #} &, lst1, {2}]
```

Answer (score 4):

An `Outer` version:

```
Flatten[ MapThread[ Outer[List, {#1}, #2] &, {lst2, lst1}], 1]
```

> {{{1, a}, {1, b}, {1, c}}, {{2, d}, {2, e}, {2, f}}}

Answer (score 3):

```
MapThread[With[{n = #2}, {n, #} & /@ #1] &, {lst1, lst2}]
```

> {{{ 1, a}, {1, b}, {1, c}}, {{2, d}, {2, e}, {2, f}}}

Answer (score 3):

**Why `MapThread`?**

While both `MapThread` and in particular `MapIndexed` are slow, using some `Transpose` based constructions, one can take `Map` (or even `ParallelMap`, if appropriate):

```
Map[Function[v, Map[{v[[2]], #} &, v[[1]]]][#] &, Transpose[Join[{lst1, lst2}]]]
```

**Edit:** I suddenly noticed that cascading `Map` was a stupid idea, so here my correction:

```
Map[
 Function[v, Transpose@{ConstantArray[v[[2]], Length[v[[1]]]], v[[1]]}
 ][#] &, Transpose[Join[{lst1, lst2}]]
]
```

In particular for large lists as usually can occur in image analysis, trying to avoid `MapThread` and `MapIndexed` is often recommended.

Answer (score 1):

Using `Table`,

```
Thread /@ Table[{lst2[[k]], lst1[[k]]}, {k, Length[lst1]}]
```

> {{{1, a}, {1, b}, {1, c}}, {{2, d}, {2, e}, {2, f}}}