# Custom SmoothHistogram3D

Tags: graphics3d, histograms, plotting

I decided to make my own SmoothHistogram3D function because I wanted to be able to specify my own bin sizes and not rely on their distribution functions so taking a cue from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8840120/2510393) and bringing it into the 3rd dimension I created this function:

```
Create3DHist[histData_] := Module[{xAxis, yAxis, intensity, yAndI, xYAndI},
    xAxis = histData[[1, 1]];
    yAxis = histData[[1, 2]];
    binCounts = histData[[2]];
    (* Sorry it gets a little messy here *)
    yAndI = Map[{yAxis[[1 ;; -2]], #}\[Transpose] &, binCounts];
    xYAndI = Partition[Flatten[MapThread[Thread[{##}] &, {xAxis[[1 ;; -2]], yAndI}]], 3];
    ListPlot3D[xYAndI, InterpolationOrder -> 3, PlotRange -> All]
]
```

(I got the idea for the xYAndI line from [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/38023/8292))

which takes the result of 2d HistogramList data and creates a 3D plot with it, like this:

```
data = RandomVariate[BinormalDistribution[.5], 1000];
histBinnedData = HistogramList[data, {{0.2}, {0.2}}];
Create3DHist[histBinnedData]
```

This produces a plot that looks like this:

[image]

However, I found I could create a much more appealing plot if I just use the binCounts and put the plot range on top of it (which is essentially the same as using `BinCounts` instead of the `HistogramList`).

```
 ListPlot3D[histBinnedData[[2]], InterpolationOrder -> 3, PlotRange -> All, DataRange -> {{-3, 3}, {-3, 3}}]
```

which produces:

[image]

which is a lot smoother. However, my issue is that my smoothing algorithm uses non-equal bin sizes, so using `DataRange` to place the numbers onto the axes is imperfect because the binCounts aren't evenly spaced, but are treated as such by `DataRange`. However, my `create3DHist` function doesn't have that issue. So after all that my question is, is there a way to combine the smoothness of the 2nd method with the x and y axis accuracy of the first method? Also, what causes this difference in smoothing even though they both use an interpolation order of 3?

**Small Update:**

I realized the reason why the second method comes out so much smoother is because mathematica uses a lot more points than just the array you give it to plot it for the second method. I used `mesh->All` to compare how many points each plot had and got this result:

[image: Comparison of the amount of actual points in each plot using the mesh option]

Is there anyway to extract the points in the second way and fix masses to them, or is there a way to fill in points in the first method so that it is more like the second method?

Comment: It seems to me that `InterpolationOrder` doesn't work properly on unstructured grids.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can apply post-processing to the regular `ListPlot3D`

```
data = RandomVariate[BinormalDistribution[.5], 1000];
{{x, y}, hist} = HistogramList[data, {{0.1}, {0.1}}, "PDF"];

{fx, fy} = Interpolation@Transpose@{Range[0.5, Length@#], #} & /@ {x, y};

ListPlot3D[GaussianFilter[Transpose@hist, {3, 1}], InterpolationOrder -> 3,
   PlotRange -> All] /. GraphicsComplex[p_, d_, opts___] :> 
  GraphicsComplex[Transpose@{fx@#, fy@#2, #3} & @@ Transpose@p, d, 
   Sequence @@ ({opts} /. (VertexNormals -> n_) :> (VertexNormals -> 
           n/Transpose@{fx'@#, fy'@#2, 1 + 0 #3} & @@ Transpose@p))]
```

[image]

P.S. Without `GaussianFilter` or another sort of smoothing it is just an interpolated histogram, not a smoothed histogram.

Comment: Thanks. This is a good solution and a lot simpler than the path I was thinking of taking. Do you know why the shading seems to disappears though?

Comment: haha I plan to use this to create plots that I smooth by altering the bin sizes, but as I was writing the question I confused myself and started calling all the histograms smooth histograms just because they looked smooth. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: @HorseWith I forget to update vertex normals. See my update.

Comment: This solution has been very helpful so far, but I've noticed that when a `ColorFunction` option is added to `ListPlot3D` the axes numbers shift and start at the origin instead of their actual x and y values. Do you know if there's a way around this?

Comment: @HorseWith It was because I wrote too simple pattern. I update it to accept additional options. Does it work now?

Comment: Ahh yes. It works great now. Thank you so much.