# Are there more readable and terse method can get this list

Tags: list-manipulation

I have a `list` like following

```
list = {{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, {6, 7, 8, 9, 10}};
```

I want get this list by a more better method:

[image]

I don't care the ordering of its elements.This is my current method.I'm missed in cloud when I manage to write it.

```
Flatten[MapThread[
  Distribute[List[##], List, List, List, UndirectedEdge] &, {{a, b}, 
   list}]]
```

> {a<->1,a<->2,a<->3,a<->4,a<->5,b<->6,b<->7,b<->8,b<->9,b<->10}

Comment: `Join@@ MapThread[Thread[#1 <-> #2] &, {{a, b}, list}]` or `Flatten` or `Catenate` to flatten list

Comment: @ubpdqn Can you make it as a answer?I think it is a better solution than me.

Comment: at least closely related: [**96803**](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/96803/5478) and [**85179**](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/85179/5478)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Since it hasn't been proposed yet:

```
Inner[UndirectedEdge, {a, b}, {{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, {6, 7, 8, 9, 10}}, Sequence]
```

> ```
> {a <-> 1, b <-> 6, a <-> 2, b <-> 7, a <-> 3,
>  b <-> 8, a <-> 4, b <-> 9, a <-> 5, b <-> 10}
> ```

(You did say that "I don't care (about) the ordering of its elements"! ;))

Comment: Wonderful!I have to say this is a magic to me.It is exact what I want.

Comment: Inner is such a nice function. Neat :)

Comment: `Inner` is certainly one of my favorite underused functions. +1

Answer (score 11):

As per request:

```
Join@@ MapThread[Thread[#1 <-> #2] &, {{a, b}, list}]
```

`Flatten` or `Catenate` to flatten list result from `MapThread`.

See comment by Kuba below.

Comment: V10 style: `Thread@*UndirectedEdge`

Comment: Or maybe can simplfy it to `Flatten[Thread/@Thread[{a,b}<->list]]`

Comment: @Kuba  I always compose :(

Comment: I'm sorry to change the choice.But the J.M. 's answer seem to more flexible.Thank again.

Comment: @yode it is your choice. Thank you for alerting me to J.M.'s answer so I can learn also.

Comment: @Kuba what does the `@*` do? it's... a little tough to search for...

Comment: @BenKalziqi Equal to `Composition`.

Answer (score 6):

How about:

```
{a, b} + list /. a_ + b_ :> a <-> b // Flatten
```

Comment: Or maybe `UndirectedEdge@@@Flatten[{a,b}+list]`.Thanks a lot.

Comment: @yode Or even terser: `# <-> #2 & @@@ Flatten[{a, b} + list]`

Comment: Well,feel pity that I cannot upvote it again. :)

Answer (score 3):

```
♭ = ## & @@ (♯  #1 <-> ♯) /@ #2 & @@@ ({##}) &
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

```
♭[{a, b}, list]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

or

```
♭2 = #2 <-> # & @@@ (## & @@@ +##) &;
♭2[{a, b}, list]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Upvote for such proficiency in using pure function. :)