# How to designate arguments in a nested Maps to get specified result?

Tags: list-manipulation, map

Say I have two lists,

```
list1 = {{a, b}, {c, d}}
list2 = {{x, y, z},{x1, y1, z1}}
```

and I want to map a function f over them to produce

```
{{f[x, {a, b}], f[y, {a,b}], f[z, {a,b}]},{f[x1, {c, d}], f[y1, {c, d}], f[z1, {c, d}]}
```

I tried some Mappings, but it seems really complex thing.
Is it possible to generate?
Thank you.

Comment: related topics: [96803](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/96803/5478), [38023](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/38023/5478)

Answer (score 2):

Modified answer from a closely related topic:

[How to use Map inside MapThread?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/38023/5478)

```
MapThread[Function[{u, b}, f[#, b] & /@ u], {list2, list1}]
```

> ```
> {
>  {f[x, {a, b}], f[y, {a, b}], f[z, {a, b}]}, 
>  {f[x1, {c, d}], f[y1, {c, d}], f[z1, {c, d}]}
> }
> ```

Answer (score 1):

This is on of those cases where an ordinary `Table` loop is by far the easiest solution:

```
Table[f[#,list1[[i]]]&/@list2[[i]],{i,2}]
```

Alternatively, you can use `MapIndexed`

```
MapIndexed[
 f[#1,list1[[#2[[1]]]]]&,
 list2,
 {2}
]
```

Comment: It's all about the speed, as my real lists are really big.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

```
Map[Function[arg, f[arg, #1}]], #2] & @@@ Transpose[{list1, list2}]
```

or, more similar to Kuba's answer

```
MapThread[Map[Function[arg, f[arg, #1]], #2] &, {list1, list2}]
```

both yielding

> ```
> {{f[x, {a, b}], f[y, {a, b}], f[z, {a, b}]},
>  {f[x1, {c, d}], f[y1, {c, d}], f[z1, {c, d}]}}
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, it's solved with Distribute.

```
Distribute[f[{#1}, #2], 
   List] & @@@ {{list2[[1]], list1[[1]]}, {list2[[2]], list1[[2]]}}
```