# Manipulating lists with constant values

Tags: list-manipulation

let us assume we have some data in the following form.

```
Table[data[[1,i,{1,2}]],{i,1,Length[data[[1]]]}]
```

This would give all $x-y$ pairs of the first file. What I want to do now is to multipliy this table with constant factors but different factors for $x$ and $y$. I found a solution for this with

```
MapThread[ Composition[Flatten, List], {xlist, #}] & /@ ylist
```

where `xlist` is

```
 Table[data[[1,i,1]],{i,1,Length[data[[1]]]}]*c1
```

and `ylist` is

```
 {Flatten[Table[data[[1,i,2]],{i,1,Length[data[[1]]]}]]}*c2
```

Is there a more comfortable way to do this?

Thank you in adavance

Sincerely

---

EDIT:

```
 test= {{0.0015856, -1486.76}, {0.00157776, -1483.45}}
```

I need :

```
 test2= {{1.5856, -148.676}, {1.57776, -148.345}}
```

So the $x$ values should be multiplied with $1000$ and the $y$ values multiplied with $0.1$

EDIT2:

Transpose is exactly what I need, thank you very much

Comment: Please state clearly what is the structure of the list you want to multiply by those constants- Is it `{{x1,y1},{x2,y2}..}`?

Comment: Your question is quite opaque. Is something like this what you mean? `pairs = {{1, 2}, {3, 4}, {5, 6}};
Transpose[{10, 100}*Transpose[pairs]]`

Comment: Closely related topics: [flexible threading](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/23395/5478) and [elegant operations on columns](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/3069/elegant-operations-on-matrix-rows-and-columns). Moreover: `test[[ ;; , 1]] *= 1000; test[[ ;; , 2]] *= .1;`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    test = {{0.0015856, -1486.76}, {0.00157776, -1483.45}};
Map[{1000*#[[1]], 0.1*#[[2]]} &, test]

(*   {{1.5856, -148.676}, {1.57776, -148.345}}   *)
```