# Mapping a function over the parts of a deeply nested Array

Tags: map, list-manipulation, inner

I have two tensors:

```
    tensorS = Array[Subscript[s, #1, #2, #3, #4] &, {2, 16, 16, 19}];
    tensorR = Array[Subscript[r, #1, #2, #3] &, {2, 16, 19}];
```

Here is a `Part` of the solution that I want to obtain:

```
    Map[Plus[tensorR[[1, 1]], #] &, tensorS[[1, 1]], {1}];
```

which is the same as:

```
    Thread[Plus[Transpose[tensorS[[1, 1]]], tensorR[[1, 1]]], List];
```

or:

```
    Inner[Plus, tensorS[[1, 1]], tensorR[[1, 1]], List];
```

The resulting tensor should have `Dimensions` `{2,16,16,19}`.

It can be seen from the part of a solution, that I want to add every element of a `tensorR` (defined by it's indices `i1,i2,i3`) to the corresponding elements of a `tensorS` `i1,i2,i3,i4`, for all indices `i3` of a `tensorS`. First `i1`, second `i2`, and third index `i3` of `tensorR` correspond to first `i1`, second `i2` and fourth `i4` index of `tensorS`, respectively.

This is the solution I want to get, but without using Table:

```
    Table[Map[Plus[tensorR[[i, j]], #] &, tensorS[[i, j]], {1}], {i, 1, 2}, {j, 1, 16}];
```

$Q$: How to use the combination od `Thread`, `Map`, `MapThread`, `Transpose` and `Inner` functions to obtain the above result? I want to avoid using `Part` and `Table`.

I'm sure that there's elegant solution that can be written in one line, but I'm not that good with deeply nested lists, so I decided to ask for your help. I've searched the forum and couldn't find the solution. I apologize if my question is a duplicate.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a way to use `MapThread`:

```
MapThread[Function[{r, s}, r + # & /@ s], {tensorR, tensorS}, 2]
```

For numeric tensors, it can be compiled to squeeze out a little more performance:

```
Compile[{{tensorR, _Real, 3}, {tensorS, _Real, 4}}
, MapThread[Function[{r, s}, r + # & /@ s], {tensorR, tensorS}, 2]
]
```

---

**Performance Measurements**

@kguler's solution has notational appeal.  Not only that, but on my machine (V10.0.0, Win7, 64-bit, 4 cpus) @kguler's method runs faster than the `Table` solution for symbolic tensors.  And, with a slight modification, it runs faster than both `Table` and `MapThread` for numeric tensors.

Here are the combinations I tried, using larger symbolic tensors and *much* larger numeric tensors:

*Symbolic Tensors*

```
$HistoryLength = 0;

symbolsS = Array[Subscript[s, #1, #2, #3, #4] &, {20, 16, 16, 190}];
symbolsR = Array[Subscript[r, #1, #2, #3] &, {20, 16, 190}];

(* bst *)
Table[symbolsR[[i, j]] + # & /@ symbolsS[[i, j]], {i, 1, 20}, {j, 1, 16}] ; // Timing
(* {6.021639, Null} *)

(* kguler *)
Transpose[Transpose[symbolsS, {1, 2, 4, 3}] + symbolsR, {1, 2, 4, 3}]; // Timing
(* {1.591210, Null} *)

(* kguler, modified *)
With[{t = Transpose[#, {1, 2, 4, 3}]&}, t[t @ symbolsS + symbolsR]]; // Timing
(* {1.045207, Null} *)

(* wreach *)
MapThread[Function[{r, s}, r + #& /@ s], {symbolsR, symbolsS}, 2]; // Timing
(* {0.967206, Null} *)

(* mr.wizard / simon woods *)
smartThread[symbolsS + symbolsR, 1]; // Timing
(* {1.528810, Null} *)
```

*Numeric Tensors*

```
SeedRandom[1234];
realsS = RandomReal[1, {20, 160, 160, 190}];
realsR = RandomReal[1, {20, 160, 190}];

(* bst *)
Table[realsR[[i, j]] + # & /@ realsS[[i, j]], {i, 1, 20}, {j, 1, 160}] ; // Timing
(* {4.290027, Null} *)

(* kguler *)
Transpose[Transpose[realsS, {1,2,4,3}] + realsR,{1,2,4,3}]; // Timing
(* {2.839218, Null} *)

(* kguler, modified *)
With[{t = Transpose[#, {1, 2, 4, 3}]&}, t[t @ realsS + realsR]]; // Timing
(* {1.731611, Null} *)

(* wreach *)
MapThread[Function[{r, s}, r + #& /@ s], {realsR, realsS}, 2]; // Timing
(* {2.433616, Null} *)

(* wreach, compiled *)
Compile[{{tensorR, _Real, 3}, {tensorS, _Real, 4}}
, MapThread[Function[{r, s}, r + # & /@ s], {tensorR, tensorS}, 2]
][realsR, realsS]; // Timing
(* {1.903212, Null} *)

(* mr.wizard / simon woods *)
smartThread[realsS + realsR, 1]; // Timing
(* {2.745618, Null} *)
```

I did not notice significant differences in performance when pinning the kernel to a single CPU.  Neither was there a noticeable difference when calling `ClearSystemCache[]` before each run.

Here is a summary table of performance, with V10, V9, V8 and V7 numbers for comparison:

```
Test                        V10  V9   V8   V7
symbolic bst                6.02 4.82 5.21 1.01
symbolic kguler             1.59 1.39 1.58 1.23
symbolic mr.W / simon woods 1.53 1.44 2.15 1.64
symbolic kguler, modified   1.05 1.22 1.30 1.03
symbolic wreach             0.97 0.78 0.87 0.95

numeric  bst                4.29 4.70 4.21 2.61
numeric  kguler             2.83 3.26 2.62 2.62
numeric  mr.W / simon woods 2.75 2.59 2.26 2.15
numeric  wreach             2.43 2.63 2.53 2.25
numeric  wreach, compiled   1.90 1.70 1.40 fail
numeric  kguler, modified   1.73 1.79 1.58 1.62
```

NOTE: The compiled `MapThread` version failed to execute properly due to a compilation error on V7.

Comment: You need another `t` wrapping `t@x +y` in the `modified kguler`. (+1 of course)

Comment: @kguler Yes, it was a transcription error.  My results stand.

Comment: @kguler I don't normally like to get drawn into microbenchmarking discussions, but I felt it important to note that your solution was running very quickly in my environment despite reports to the contrary.  My tests were aimed primarily at trying to determine whether this was a fluke result, or consistent.  It seems consistent, under these conditions at least.

Comment: @WReach Thanks a lot. This was the answer that I was looking for. Before accepting your solution, I needed some time to build my calculation model and test the solution within, which fits in perfectly.

Answer (score 4):

Use the second argument of `Transpose`: transpose the last two levels of `tensorS`, add `tensorR`, transpose the last two levels again:

```
tensorS = Array[Subscript[s, #1, #2, #3, #4] &, {2, 16, 16, 19}];
tensorR = Array[Subscript[r, #1, #2, #3] &, {2, 16, 19}];
opres = Table[Map[Plus[tensorR[[i, j]], #]&, tensorS[[i, j]], {1}], {i, 1, 2}, {j, 1, 16}];

res1 = Transpose[(Transpose[tensorS, {1, 2, 4, 3}] + tensorR), {1, 2, 4, 3}];
Dimensions[res1]
(* {2,16,16,19 *)
opres == res1
(* True *)
```

Comment: Certainly +1 for elegance. Your solution is about 30% slower than the OP's `Table`- approach (if this matters at all)

Comment: Thanks @eldo. Yes, `Table` is much faster - by over 50% on my machine.

Comment: Performance matters a lot, since I need a solution that will work fast on higher-rank tensors.

Comment: On my machine, this method runs faster than the `Table` approach, and `With[{t = Transpose[#, {1, 2, 4, 3}]&}, t @ symbolsS + symbolsR]` is even faster still (see the testing details in my response).

Comment: I transcribed that incorrectly, I meant `With[{t = Transpose[#, {1, 2, 4, 3}]&}, t[t @ symbolsS + symbolsR]]`. It is slightly faster.

Answer (score 4):

1. Load Simon Woods's `smartThread` from: [How can I make threading more flexible?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/23395/how-can-i-make-threading-more-flexible/23396#23396)
2. Write simply:

   ```
   smartThread[tensorR + tensorS, 1]
   ```
3. Be happy.

:-)

Comment: Thanks for pointing out. I accepted WReach's answer just because it works great for me, and I didn't have that much time to test smartThread's behavior within my calculation model.