# How to multiply specific columns in a matrix of data?

Tags: list-manipulation, matrix

So I need to make a plot of some ~2000 data points I have from a spreadsheet. I'm able to import the data just fine, it stores it like so

```
sundat
```

> {{280.,0.082},{280.5,0.099},......{3995.,0.0087},{4000.,0.00868}}

And I can call individual data sets or points like so

```
sundat[[1]]
```

> {280.,0.082}

```
sundat[[1,1]]
```

> 280.

There are 2002 sets of two points of data. Now I can plot it fine using ListPlot, but the raw data I have is in messy units that I want to convert to mks units. I have the conversion factor for each column, but I have no idea how to do this. I presume I need to make a new list to apply this to, but trying something like

```
data2 = {{sundat[[All,1]]*(conversion1)},{sundat[[All,2]]*(conversion2)}}
```

just totally messes up the table.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: A variety of list manipulation methods can be found [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/3069/7167)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
sundat = {{280., 0.082}, {280.5, 0.099}, {3995., 0.0087}, {4000., 0.00868}};
conversionfactors = {2., .5};

data2 = Transpose[conversionfactors Transpose[sundat]]
```

or

```
data2 = conversionfactors # & /@ sundat
```

both give

```
(* {{560.,0.041},{561.,0.0495},{7990.,0.00435},{8000.,0.00434}} *)
```

Comment: Both of these work perfectly. Thank you!!

Comment: @Amara, my pleasure. Thank you for the accept. And welcome to MMA.SE.

Answer (score 6):

You can also use [`Dot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Dot.html):

```
sundat.{{2., 0}, {0, .5}}

(*  {{560., 0.041}, {561., 0.0495}, {7990., 0.00435}, {8000., 0.00434}}  *)
```

Comment: For some reason I always forget this form, though I have been shown it and even used it myself (e.g. [(38180)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/38180)).  I don't like the theoretically wasted operations, but it's so well optimized it is *still* often faster than alternatives.

Answer (score 2):

Since Version 13.1 there is `Threaded`:

```
sundat = {{280., 0.082}, {280.5, 0.099}, {3995., 0.0087}, {4000., 0.00868}};

sundat * Threaded[{2., .5}]
```

{{560., 0.041}, {561., 0.0495}, {7990., 0.00435}, {8000., 0.00434}}

Answer (score 1):

Although I prefer kguler's double `Transpose` you could also use [`Inner`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Inner.html):

```
sundat = {{280., 0.082}, {280.5, 0.099}, {3995., 0.0087}, {4000., 0.00868}};

Inner[Times, sundat, {2., .5}, List]
```

> ```
> {{560., 0.041}, {561., 0.0495}, {7990., 0.00435}, {8000., 0.00434}}
> ```

Or leveraging Simon's solution from: [How can I make threading more flexible?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/23395/121)

```
smartThread[sundat {2., .5}]
```

> ```
> {{560., 0.041}, {561., 0.0495}, {7990., 0.00435}, {8000., 0.00434}}
> ```

---

A related question:  [Mapping a function over the parts of a deeply nested Array](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/58971/121)

See also: [Elegant operations on matrix rows and columns](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/3069/121)

Comment: Thanks Mr.Wizard, I always get an upvote or two for that when you use it :-)

Comment: @Simon And well you should!