# Inconsistency in arithmetic on list elements

Tags: list-manipulation

As expected,

```
{a,b,c} - {a,a,a}
(* {0, -a+b, -a+c} *)
```

Or the same result can be obtained with less typing, thanks to implicit duplication of the subtrahend:

```
{a,b,c} - a
(* {0, -a+b, -a+c} *)
```

Likewise as expected,

```
{{a,b,c}, {d,e,f}, {g,h,i}} - {{a,b,c}, {a,b,c}, {a,b,c}}
(* {{0,0,0}, {-a+d, -b+e, -c+f}, {-a+g, -b+h, -c+i}} *)
```

But in this case the abbreviated query acts quite differently:

```
{{a,b,c}, {d,e,f}, {g,h,i}} - {a,b,c}
(* {{0, -a+b, -a+c}, {-b+d, -b+e, -b+f}, {-c+g, -c+h, -c+i}} *)
```

What is the distinction I am missing here?

Comment: You have participated in this community sufficiently to be aware of how code should be formatted in questions. So why aren't formatting your code in the community style?

Comment: What you are missing is a thorough understanding of the [`Listable`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Listable.html) property of arithmetic functions. You should study the documentation concerning Listable carefully. Especially, the **Details** section.

Comment: [closely related](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/23395/5478)

Comment: I would like to format my code, but I don't know where to find the instructions for doing so. Of course I see other people's formatting results, but I don't see how they are achieving them.

Comment: @RalphDratman http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/formatting

Answer (score 3):

The reason that something like `{a, b} + {c, d}` gives `{a + b, c + d}` is because `Plus` has the `Listable` attribute, meaning that it automatically threads over lists. (You might consider the result "as expected" but you should keep in mind that not all functions behave this way. For example `Rule` is not listable and so `{a, b} -> {c, d}` gives `{a, b} -> {c, d}`, i.e. no change.) As noted in your question and in the documentation, *"Arguments that are not lists are copied as many times as there are elements in the lists"*, so that `{a, b} + c` gives `{a + c, b + c}`.

An important feature, not well explained in the documentation, is that this automatic threading starts at the **outermost** level of the expression. So for example when you     do:

```
{{a, b}, {c, d}} + {e, f}
```

*Mathematica* sees "a list of 2 items" plus "another list of 2 items" and threads Plus over those lists. At this initial step the fact that `{a, b}` is itself a list is not important, it could equally well be an image of a horse or any other expression.

After threading Plus over the outer lists the expression looks like

```
{{a, b} + e, {c, d} + f}
```

at which point *Mathematica* evaluates the subexpressions `{a, b} + e` and `{c, d} + f`, which involves more automatic threading over the lists, giving the final result:

```
{{a + e, b + e}, {c + f, d + f}}
```

You can see the order of evaluation for yourself using `Trace`:

```
Trace[{{a, b}, {c, d}} + {e, f}] // Column
```

> ```
> {{a, b}, {c, d}} + {e, f}
> {{a, b} + e, {c, d} + f}
> {{a, b} + e, {a + e, b + e}}
> {{c, d} + f, {c + f, d + f}}
> {{a + e, b + e}, {c + f, d + f}}
> ```

Comment: I appreciate your taking the time to explain that.  "... not well explained in the documentation." The documentation and help system definitely is improving, but it is still not a straightforward task to master this language.

Comment: This comment was a mistake, and now I can't figure out how to delete it. I am sorry.

Comment: @RalphDratman, if you haven't already, I recommend reading the page on [Evaluation](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/Evaluation.html), it will help you to understand how *Mathematica* proceeds through the evaluation and why attributes like Listable work the way they do.

Comment: Simon Woods, thank you. I now see from the "closely related" answer, pointed out by Kuba, that you have thought about this and related issues at length. Apparently my mind is not properly wired for nested lists. In fact I spend far too much Mathematica time figuring out whether to write {2}, or maybe 2, or possibly 3 at the end of a Map or Apply construct.

Answer (score 0):

```
desired = {{a, b, c}, {d, e, f}, {g, h, i}} - {{a, b, c}, {a, b, c}, {a, b, 
c}}
```

> {{0, 0, 0}, {-a + d, -b + e, -c + f}, {-a + g, -b + h, -c + i}}

{{a, b, c}, {d, e, f}, {g, h, i}} - {a, b, c} is interpreted as

```
{{a, b, c}, {d, e, f}, {g, h, i}} - {a, b, c} ==
 {{a, b, c} - a, {d, e, f} - b, {g, h, i} - c}
```

> True

What you are seeking is

```
desired == (# - {a, b, c} & /@ {{a, b, c}, {d, e, f}, {g, h, i}})
```

> True