# How to avoid repeatedly entering a point into an expression

Tags: list-manipulation

I have this snippet:

```
points = CirclePoints[{10, 0}, 4];
```

The result will be an array of 2D coordinates.

> `{{10, 0}, {0, 10}, {-10, 0}, {0, -10}}`

I want to shift all of them by a certain vector $\mathbf{p}$.

```
p = {4, 5};
points + {p, p, p, p}
```

Nothing is wrong up to now. But instead of a square, suppose I want a dodecagon. Then the code changes to:

```
points = CirclePoints[{10, 0}, 12];
p = {4, 5};
points + {p, p, p, p, p, p, p, p, p, p, p, p}
```

How can I avoid entering all those repeated `p`'s ?

Comment: You can use `#+p& /@ points` .

Comment: Can you explain this structure? what is `/@` (for example).

Comment: Whenever you encounter an unfamiliar symbol in *Mathematica*, highlight it and press F1.

Comment: @J.M. Ok. but it'd be better to turn that solution into an answer./// Is that possible? that'd be great!

Comment: @AHB I don't think so because if something is easy to find in docs then topics are closed. On the other hand, they may be closed as duplicates too. Here is a closely related topic about [Flexible threading](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/23395/5478)

Comment: On a final note, look up `TranslationTransform[]` as well.

Comment: @Szabolcs Shouldn't the correct syntax be `in = p + # & /@ points;`?

Comment: @AHB. I don't see the difference between what you wrote and what Kuba wrote other than `#` and `p` switching places, and that won't make a difference in the output.

Comment: Alternative: `displaced = points + ConstantArray[p, 12]`

Comment: Reconsideration: Actually I think the best way to do what is requested is `CirclePoints[{4, 5}, {10, 0}, 12]`

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
 points /. {x_, y_} -> {x, y} + p

(* {{14, 5}, {4, 15}, {-6, 5}, {4, -5}} *)
```

Have fun!

Comment: I'm not fully comfortable with this solution for the following reason:  `{{1, 2}, {3, 4}, {5, 6}} /. {x_, y_} -> {x, y} + {a, b}` gives `{{1 + a, 2 + b}, {3 + a, 4 + b}, {5 + a, 6 + b}}` but `{{1, 2}, {3, 4}} /. {x_, y_} -> {x, y} + {a, b}` gives `{{1 + a, 2 + a}, {3 + b, 4 + b}}`.  `Replace[..., {1}]` instead of `ReplaceAll` would avoid this.

Comment: @Szabolcs You are right. Have you an idea, why this phenomenon is met with the list of two items and disappears in the list with the three ones?

Comment: That is because if the list if `{{1,2}, {3,4}}` then the pattern will match as `x = {1,2}` and `y = {3,4}` first.  `ReplaceAll` has the property that it matches elements "from the outside towards the inside", i.e. it first tries the complete expression.  If that does match, it tries its subexpressions.  Then the subexpressions of subexpressions, etc.  Until there is a match.  When there is a match, it performs the replacement and doesn't look at deeper subexpressions anymore.

Comment: With `Replace`, we can control at which level to do the pattern matching.  Try both `Replace[{{1, 2}, {3, 4}}, {x_, y_} -> {x, y} + {a, b}, {1}]` and `Replace[{{1, 2}, {3, 4}}, {x_, y_} -> {x, y} + {a, b}, {0}]` and see the different results.  Now try to ask Replace to match at *all* levels: `Replace[{{1, 2}, {3, 4}}, {x_, y_} -> {x, y} + {a, b}, {0, Infinity}]`.  The result is now `{{1 + 2 a, 2 + a + b}, {3 + a + b, 4 + 2 b}}`.  This is because of two differences with `ReplaceAll`:  (1) the search is done from the inside towards the outside, starting with the deepest subexpressions ...

Comment: ... (2) once a match is found, the replacement does not stop.  `Replace` keeps looking at larger containing expressions and keeps doing more replacements.

Comment: Why would anybody use this when `CirclePoints[{4, 5}, {10, 0}, 12]` will do the job? That is: the built-in function already provides translation.

Comment: OK, I tried to illustrate this and it turns out I don't understand `Replace`.  In short, I don't know why it prints `{1,2}` and `{3,4}` a *second* time a the end:  `Replace[{{1, 2}, {3, 4}}, {x_, 
   y_} :> (Print[{x, y}]; {x, y} + {a, b}), {0, Infinity}]`.  I have a vague feeling I asked about this once but now I can't remember ..

Comment: I figured it out.  The reason is that `Replace` does all replacements on the expression first without allowing anything to be evaluated.  When the replacements are complete, it allows the full expression to get finally evaluated.  Illustration:  `Replace[{1, 2}, x_ :> Hold[Print[x]; x], {0, Infinity}]` gives `Hold[Print[{Hold[Print[1]; 1], Hold[Print[2]; 2]}]; {Hold[Print[1]; 
   1], Hold[Print[2]; 2]}]`.  If we now remove `Hold` and allow `Print` to evaluate, we get exactly the sequence of expression we observed above.