# Multiplying/dividing two unequal lists

Tags: list-manipulation

I have two list which are not equal dimension:

```
listA = {{{1, 2}, {2, 2}, {3, 4}}, {{1, 1}, {2, 2}, {3, 3}}};
listB = {{4, 4}, {5, 5}};
```

And I want to divide them or multiply the such as the results has the same dimensions, for the first dimension, it should look like:

```
(#*listB[[1]]) & /@ listA[[1]]
```

but I would like to do it all at once so that the result has the same dimension as `listA`. I bet it has probably been answered here but I cannot seem to find it. Therefore link to an existing answer is also great.

Comment: How about `Table[(#*listB[[i]]) & /@ listA[[i]], {i, Length[listB]}]`

Comment: `MapThread[(Function[{x}, x #2] /@ #1) &, {listA, listB}]`?

Comment: Related: [(23395)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/23395/121)

Answer (score 5):

Some overhead but the most clean solution I could muster:

`Diagonal@Outer[Times, listB, listA, 1, 2]`

`{{{4, 8}, {8, 8}, {12, 16}}, {{5, 5}, {10, 10}, {15, 15}}}`

Answer (score 3):

Using Simon Woods's [`smartThread`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/23396/121) one may write:

```
smartThread[listA*listB, 1]
```

> ```
> {{{4, 8}, {8, 8}, {12, 16}}, {{5, 5}, {10, 10}, {15, 15}}}
> ```

For fun here is a way using [`Inactive`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Inactive.html) and [`Activate`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Activate.html), assuming list elements are atomic:

```
Map[Inactive, Quiet[listA*listB], {-2}] // Activate
```

Answer (score 1):

```
a = {{{1, 2}, {2, 2}, {3, 4}}, {{1, 1}, {2, 2}, {3, 3}}};
b = {{4, 4}, {5, 5}};
```

With `ReplacePart` and `Threaded` (new in 13.1)

```
ReplacePart[i_ :> a[[i]] * Threaded @ b[[i]] @ a
```

{{{4, 8}, {8, 8}, {12, 16}}, {{5, 5}, {10, 10}, {15, 15}}}

Answer (score 1):

Using `KroneckerProduct` and `TensorRank`:

```
listA = {{{1, 2}, {2, 2}, {3, 4}}, {{1, 1}, {2, 2}, {3, 3}}};
listB = {{4, 4}, {5, 5}};

tr = TensorRank[listA];

{#[[1]][[;; tr]], #[[-1]][[;; tr]]} &@KroneckerProduct[listB, listA]

(*{{{4, 8}, {8, 8}, {12, 16}}, {{5, 5}, {10, 10}, {15, 15}}}*)
```